# Upgrading Facebook SDK using cocoapods

Tags: ios, facebook, sdk, cocoapods

I am trying to update my ios app dependencies(facebook ios sdk and branch) using cocoapods,
my initial Podfile contents are:-

```
platform :ios, '8.1'
pod 'Facebook-iOS-SDK', '3.18'
pod 'BranchInvite'
```

which are written in

I am trying to migrate facebook ios sdk from 3.18 to 3.24.1 and branch to the latest one. I get the following error on running:

```
$> pod update

[!] Unable to satisfy the following requirements:

- `Facebook-iOS-SDK (= 3.18)` required by `Podfile`
```

when I try to increaese my facebook sdk version to 3.18 to 3.24 or any 4.x, it gives similar failure with 3.18.

Then I followed the guidelines on [this page](https://cocoapods.org/pods/Facebook-iOS-SDK), I removed the older Facebook ios sdk dependency, ran pod update(which deleted the folder FacebookSDK) and I was left with the following build error, wherever FBSession was being used from FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h:

```
use of undeclared identifier FBSession
```

What is the correct way to upgrading the facebook ios sdk using Pods?

Comment: `FBSession`  is no longer available in the most recent version of the SDK.

Comment: @albertamg what should be done for the recent versions?

Comment: @albertamg is there a single replacement which will manage what FBSession did?

Comment: I think the `FBSession` class was removed in 4.0. See [iOS SDK, Upgrading from 3.x to 4.x](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/upgrading-4.x) for more details. I'm sorry I cannot be of more help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should delete the pods and reinstall them.
Delete Pods folder and Podfile.lock file. Update your pod file with

```
pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
pod 'FBSDKShareKit'
pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
```

Comment: I did change the podfile. It is signaling that 'use of undeclared identifier FBSession', I read it is deprecated, but there is not guidance to what should use in place of them.

By the way, rather than deleting pods and reinstalling them, a cleaner method is just altering the Podfile and run 'pod update', which takes care of the removal/update/reinstall gracefully.